# Suitable database for json type data

Tags: nosql

I am trying to find out which database will be more suitable to store JSON type data in my case.
Let's say I have this data at some point:

```
[
  {
    "parent_name": "A",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "1.1",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "B",
            "version": "5.2"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "C",
            "version": "9.7"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After one update I have something like this:

```
[
  {
    "parent_name": "A",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "1.1",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "B",
            "version": "5.2"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "C",
            "version": "9.7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "D",
            "version": "3.9"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

After another:

```
[
  {
    "parent_name": "A",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "1.1",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "B",
            "version": "5.2"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "C",
            "version": "9.7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "D",
            "version": "3.9"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "E",
            "version": "20.8"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Maybe after another:

```
[
  {
    "parent_name": "A",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "1.1",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "B",
            "version": "5.2"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "C",
            "version": "9.7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "version": "1.2",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "D",
            "version": "3.9"
          },
          {
            "dep_name": "E",
            "version": "20.8"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent_name": "X",
    "versions": [
      {
        "version": "0.2",
        "dependencies": [
          {
            "dep_name": "A",
            "version": "1.2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am writing my scripts in Python. I am confused about whether I should go for SQL or NoSQL type database for this specific case. Can you please let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's the deal, querying your data is going to be inefficient and require more work to manage, if you keep it *all* denormalized in JSON, regardless of which type of database you choose.

Even in a NoSQL database, you'll want to proactively normalize the data into their own collections and columns appropriately, so that it can be directly queried and managed. NoSQL databases are useful for when the structure changes unpredictably and more frequently than you're able to manage.

But your JSON data looks fairly well structured. I see two objects that would be two tables in a SQL database: `Versions` and `Dependencies`. There appears to be a one-to-many relationship between `Versions` and `Dependencies` which you can formally define with a foreign key. You may even have a case for a `Parents` table if there's more information about them then what's currently shown, otherwise the `ParentName` can just be a column in the `Versions` table. Because of this, I'd recommend one of the mainstream modern SQL databases.

Answer (score -1):

You should go for SQL Database as it is easy to use relationships and easy to get dependencies of current version record using relationship

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).